# linq-like sum function in python

Tags: python, linq

I started programming in python after a time I was programming in c#, and in c# I used quite often did things like the following:

```
list.sum(x => x * 2);
```

where `list` contains some kind of a number. 
is there any thing like this in python? for example i want to do this:

```
>> arr = range(1,10)
>> linq_like_sum(lambda x :  x**2 , arr)
```

and get the sum of squares of arr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a generator expression:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
sum(x*x for x in lst)

> 55
```

Answer (score 4):

Try a generator expression with the built-in `sum()`:

```
sum(x ** 2 for x in arr)
```